# Regular expression correction

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match the strings with this format  `5-29-2014 3-24-01 PM`. in other way `5-29-2014 h-MM-SS tt`

Here `5-29-2014` part never changes and `3-24-01 PM`  will be changing.

So some matching strings are like

- 5-29-2014 1-02-01 PM
- 5-29-2014 12-00-01 PM
- 5-29-2014 3-24-01 AM
- 5-29-2014 10-59-59 AM

This is what I tried so far, and it didn't work

`^5-29-2014 (?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)(\\s*[ap]m?)$`

Any one can suggest a regex for this?

Comment: Try `5-29-2014 (\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (AM|PM)`

Comment: @AlphaDelta: That will match "5-29-2014 100-100-100 PM" which probably isn't what the OP intended.

Comment: @AlphaDelta: it match this `5-29-2014 3-94-01 PM` minutes part is > 59.

Comment: `^5-29-2014 (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-[0-5]\d-[0-5]\d\s*[apAP][mM]$`

Comment: You've currently got lower case "am" and "pm", but your sample inputs always have capitalized ones. Could it be as simple as that? If not, please give more details than "it doesn't work" - does it match strings you don't want it to match? Does it *not* match strings you *do* want to match? Please show input along with expected and actual output.

Comment: Also, please clarify as to whether the hour value is meant to be a 24-hour value or not. Currently it looks like you're trying to validate that the number is between 0 and 23 inclusive, but that makes little sense when you've got an AM/PM value as well.

Comment: Sorry, try `5-29-2014 ([01]?[0-2]|[1-9])-([0-5]?[0-9])-([0-5]?[0-9]) (AM|PM)`

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It doesn't match my string. and hours in 12 hr. Thats why it gets AM PM

Comment: It looks as though it's working fine http://www.regexr.com/39099

Comment: @AlphaDelta: Your regex works fine. May be you can post as a answer.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: But your regex accepts an hour value of "23" for example - why? Basically it seems geared towards a 24-hour value... And again, why are you specifying *lower case* am and pm when your values are upper case? And *which* string value isn't matching - all of them? Just one? Always be specific in your question - "it doesn't work" is *never* specific enough.

Comment: There you go @NayanaAdassuriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for;

```
5-29-2014 (1[0-2]|[1-9])-([0-5]?[0-9])-([0-5]?[0-9]) (AM|PM)
```

And you can see it in action [here](http://www.regexr.com/39099).

Comment: By the way the answer posted by the  Ulugbek Umirov also works. It is here with a minor change `^5-29-2014 (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-[0-5]\d-[0-5]\d\s*[AP][M]$`